# Straight line in html

Tags: html, utf-8, character, line, separator

What's the best way to draw a whole single line using html?

What I want is something like this:

---

but shorter.

I know about the existence [[1]](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp)[[2]](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) of `&horbar;` (―), `&mdash;` (—), `&ndash` (–), figure dash etc...

But the problem is that they are not cross platform / cross browser: sometimes I get this --- behaviour instead of this ___ but in the middle.

I didn't test all of them, but using the *horizontal line* does not work on Windows Chrome (while it does on Ubuntu and Android), the *em dash* works on Windows Chrome but does not work on Firefox and the *en dash* does not work neither on Android Chrome, Windows Chrome or Firefox.

I know that I could just make a span/div with a border and relatively position it, but the problem is that it would be fixed length, while I need a line which extends based on the content (so that `---this---` could be longer than `---this longer one---`), since I have the same content displayed with different languages.

**So, is there any character able to draw a cross-browser solid line?**

UPDATE: This is what I need

[image: This is what I need]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want but maybe some CSS might help you?
I don't think using a character for embellishment is appropriate here.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.with-line {
  display: block;
}

.with-line:before,
.with-line:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<span class="with-line">Short</span>

<span class="with-line">Longer</span>

<span class="with-line">Real long sentence to show the length</span>
```

Comment: No, this is not what I need, I want a line that stretches with the text...

Comment: A character would never have a dynamic width so I doubt that's a possibility but let's see :)

Comment: Sorry, I noticed only now that this line does not have dynamic width, so what I need is the exact opposite: a line longer when the text is longer (see my edited question).

Comment: And how long should it be?

Comment: about 3 characters long (or 3 `ch`)

Comment: I edited the post. That's a much much easier problem to solve and I reduced the code a bit to make it leaner.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I found out a bunch of different lines, some of which are cross browser as far as I could test:

```html
horizontal bar: &horbar;&horbar;&horbar;&horbar;<br />
em dash: &mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;<br />
en dash: &ndash;&ndash;&ndash;&ndash;<br />
hypen: &hyphen;&hyphen;&hyphen;&hyphen;<br />
dash: &dash;&dash;&dash;&dash;<br />
box drawings light horizontal: &boxh;&boxh;&boxh;&boxh;<br />
fullwidth low line: &lowbar;&lowbar;&lowbar;&lowbar;<br />
minus: &minus;&minus;&minus;&minus;<br />
combining overline: &oline;&oline;&oline;&oline;<br />
three-em dash: &#11835;&#11835;&#11835;&#11835;<br />
horizontal line extension: &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;<br />
horizontal scan line 7: &#9148;&#9148;&#9148;&#9148;<br />
figure dash: &#8210;&#8210;&#8210;&#8210;<br />
```

Sources: [1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm), [2](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

at the moment `&boxh;`, `&lowbar;`, `&oline;`, `&#9472;`, `&#9135;`, `&#9148;` are the only ones which work on every platform.

Please let me know if you find something else or if one of the above does not work on some platforms.

ANyway, for the moment I think I'm going to use @Dominik's solution anyway